# Getting Scene Names at Runtime/Creating Scenes at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene

I want to build a RTS Game in Unity version 5.3.xxx.
I want to have a dropdown menu to select the level i want to play.
I dont want to hardcode it in so how do i get the scene names at runtime?
This is neccessary to add new Levels ingame.
Thats the next question then. How do i create new scenes and add them to build path at runtime to use them ingame? for example in an map editor?

I cant use the UnityEditor to go through all scenes with foreeach, because its a editor class and these dont get into the final build..

Thanks

Comment: You don't create new scenes and add them at runtime. You use Unity's UI and button click events, which you can then do `scenemanager.loadscene` in the button click callback function. Look at UI tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As of Unity 5.x, there are much more robust options for managing scenes at runtime.**

Getting the current scene name:

`SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name`

---

Getting a list of all scene names added to the SceneManager:

```
var numScenes = SceneManager.sceneCount;
List<string> sceneNames = new List<string>(numScenes);

for (int i=0; i < numScenes; ++i)
{
   sceneNames.Add(StageManager.GetSceneAt(i).name);
}
```

---

Creating new scene at runtime:

```
var newScene = SceneManager.CreateScene(string sceneName);
```

---

Adding new scenes to the build path at runtime:

*I'm fairly certain this is not possible nor recommended.*

*If you want the functionality of a level editor in your game, consider writing your own method of serializing a scene so that it can be deserialized into an empty scene at runtime.*

---

**See also:**

- [SceneManagement.Scene](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.html)
- [SceneManagement.SceneManager](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain the lastpoint a bit cleaerer? I want to have an level editor later or just an folder to put maps(scenes?) in and the game has to usw it, but scenes have to be in the buildpath as far as i know.

Comment: Another question here: You use GetSceneAt(i).name Do you mean SceneManager.GetSceneAt(i).name ? If yes. it only has 1 scene, my main Scene not the others. Index greater 1 is out of bounds. But the scenes are added to the build path? Why arent they added to the scenemanager?

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here on the Unity forums](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1115796/scenemanagergetallscenes-only-returns-the-current.html), SceneManager.[GetSceneAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetSceneAt.html) only works with **currently active** scenes.

For now, you need to use work-arounds to get **all** scenes in your build during run-time, using [EditorBuildSettings.scenes](https://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/EditorBuildSettings-scenes.html). You are right, this is only available during editing, but you can simply make sure to cache them to a run-time asset or component before building.

Also note that the [documentation example for EditorBuildSettings.scenes](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorBuildSettings-scenes.html) actually gives you a pretty powerful script to grab all scenes, including those that have not been added to the build settings (and even adds them to the build settings, using a single button click)! You can just use that to save all scene paths to a component or `ScriptableObject` which will then be available during run-time.

Answer (score 1):

Old I know, but it matched my search, so I'm posting my solution. This seems to be possible at runtime now using [SceneUtility.GetScenePathByBuildIndex](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneUtility.GetScenePathByBuildIndex.html)

What I did:

```
var sceneNames = new List<string>();
var regex = new Regex(@"([^/]*/)*([\w\d\-]*)\.unity");
for (int i = 0; i < SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings; i++)
{
    var path = SceneUtility.GetScenePathByBuildIndex(i);
    var name = regex.Replace(path, "$2");
    sceneNames.Add(name);
}
```

[Regex Credit](https://davikingcode.com/blog/retrieving-the-names-of-your-scenes-at-runtime-with-unity/?unapproved=7702&moderation-hash=9d3e3127edec567a0f33c15010c91ab2#comment-7702)

Comment: You can also use System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension instead of the regex.